# Unable to get valid assertion involving Jasmine spy on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write tests for a service that simply takes a HttpResponse as input and outputs a console.error in case the HttpResponse involves an error.

The service works fine and even in the browser instance that Karma populates, I can see the console.error, but the test I wrote asserting the same is failing. Not sure why.

Here's the test:-

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from "./global-error-handler.service";

describe("GlobalErrorHandler Service", () => {
  let service: GlobalErrorHandler;
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new GlobalErrorHandler();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    service = null;
  });

  it("should catch HttpErrors and output to console", () => {
    let error = new HttpErrorResponse({
      url: "Some url",
      error: { message: "error message details" },
      status: 404
    });
    let errorLog = {
      status: error.status,
      message: error.message,
      details: error.error.message
    };
    service.handleError(error);
    console.error = jasmine.createSpy("error");
    expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Here's the service that I'm testing:-

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class GlobalErrorHandler {
  constructor() {}
  handleError(error: any) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      const errorToShow = {
        status: error.status,
        message: error.message,
        details: error.error.message
      };
      console.error(`Backend returned this error => `, errorToShow);
    } else {
      console.error(`An error occurred => "${error.message}"`);
    }
    // Throwing error...
    throw error;
    // enable the following line to show notification...
    // this.errorNotifier.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

Here's the test output on the terminal:-

```
ng test
10% building 7/8 modules 1 active ...tarter-app-seven/src sync /\.spec\.ts$/25 01 2019 17:24:12.806:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
25 01 2019 17:24:12.817:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
25 01 2019 17:24:12.818:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
25 01 2019 17:24:12.830:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
25 01 2019 17:24:23.171:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/    
25 01 2019 17:24:23.405:INFO [Chrome 71.0.3578 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket FvdOGo3cHANej7U5AAAA with id 24264291
ERROR: 'Backend returned this error => ', Object{status: 404, message: 'Http failure response for Some url: 404 undefined', details: 'error message details'}
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.307 secs)
ERROR: 'Backend returned this error => ', Object{status: 404, message: 'Http failure response Chrome 71.0.3578 (Linux 0.0.0) GlobalErrorHandler Service should catch HttpErrors and output to console FAILED
  HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for Some url: 404 undefined
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.311 secs)
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Linux 0.0.0) GlobalErrorHandler Service should catch HttpErrors and output to console FAILED
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (1 FAILED) (0.359 secs / 0.311 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 3 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 3 SUCCESS
```

Screenshot of browser test instance:-

[image: Screenshot showing the desired console.error output, but also its test failing]

I expect the test to pass, especially when the browser actually returns a console.error. I'm new to testing and Jasmine. So it's likely something silly, please help me out. Thanks in advance :)

**Update:-**

Tried rearranging the lines to have the spy created before the service is called (in the beforeEach section) but got the same result:-

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from "./global-error-handler.service";

describe("GlobalErrorHandler Service", () => {
  let service: GlobalErrorHandler;
  let errorSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new GlobalErrorHandler();
    errorSpy = jasmine.createSpy('error');
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    service = null;
  });

  it("should catch HttpErrors and output to console", () => {
    let error = new HttpErrorResponse({
      url: "Some url",
      error: { message: "error message details" },
      status: 404
    });
    let errorLog = {
      status: error.status,
      message: error.message,
      details: error.error.message
    };
    service.handleError(error);
    expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**Solution:-**

Got it to work, the problem was that there was a throw statement in my method which was cancelling the test before it reached the expect statement. Here I am using a promise to call that function so that the expect statement only gets called when the method returns an error.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class GlobalErrorHandler {
  constructor() {}
  /**
   * If an error occurs, we display it in the console with pertinent details
   * @param error the error object
   */
  handleError(error: any) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      const errorToShow = {
        status: error.status,
        message: error.message,
        details: error.error.message
      };
      console.error(`Backend returned this error => `, errorToShow);
    } else {
      // If error is not an instance of HttpErrorResponse...
      console.error(`An error occurred => "${error.message}"`);
    }
    throw new Error(error.message);
    // enable the following line to show notification...
    // this.errorNotifier.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

Test:-

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from "./global-error-handler.service";

describe("GlobalErrorHandler Service", () => {
  let service: GlobalErrorHandler;
  let error;
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new GlobalErrorHandler();
    error = new HttpErrorResponse({
      url: "Some url",
      error: { message: "error message details" },
      status: 404
    });
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    service = null;
    error = null;
  });

  it("should show output error message to console", () => {
    const errorSpy = spyOn(console, "error");
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(()=>service.handleError(error));
    })
    promise.then(()=> {},()=>expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled());
  });

  it("should throw error when called", () => {
    expect(() => {
      service.handleError(error);
    }).toThrow(new Error(error.message));
  });
});
```

Comment: shouldnt you create the spy before handling the error?

Comment: Part of the solution was to create the spy before calling the method, as Jota has suggested, but also the other part was that the actual method was throwing an error which prevented the test from reaching the expect statement. So I removed the `throw error` line from the method and the test works as expected. I'm not sure why I put that throw error line in there, but there is probably a way to write the test so that it will assert properly even when the method has the throw statement. Will update if I find it. For now I've updated the OP at the end with the code that worked.

Comment: Updated the solution in the OP with code that would work even with the throw statement in. I basically had to call the original method within a promise. Phew, learned a lot about testing just by working through the solution to my own question :D

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the spy after handling the error, thats why the assertion fails.

Try with the following:

```
const errorSpy = spyOn(console,"error");
service.handleError(error);
expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Tried this, got `Property 'spyOn' does not exist on type 'typeof jasmine'.` I am using these versions of jasmine:-
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",

Also I tried to just rearrange the lines as you suggest in principle, but that resulted in the same error. I've updated the OP with the lines I tried.

Comment: @RawCode My bad, its simply `spyOn`. Updated answer

Comment: thanks for helping, but it didn't work. But I got it work after doing a bit of research and referring to the official documentation. Apparently the syntax has changed for Jasmine 2.0 and while this would work on the older version, the new version required different way of initiating and asserting the spies. I've added an answer with the code that worked. Again, thanks for the effort to help :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for this confusion. I got the code to work with different syntax, but while doing so I also restructured the service method itself and turns out the problem was with the service method, because I tried using the code you provided here and it works then too! So I didn't need to change the jasmine syntax. I am updating the OP with the code that worked. Thanks :)